# What does "was los sein" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

***Im kleinen Fischerhafen ist immer was los.***

My guess is:

> There's always something going on in the small fishing harbour.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this context yes it means "Something's always going on/happening". In the example "was" is short for "etwas" (*something*).

"Los" can have other meanings:

> Was ist los mit dir? (=What's wrong with you?)
>
> Los geht's (=off we go)
>
> loslassen (=let go)
>
> losfahren (=hit the road)
>
> -los (suffix) (=-less)

Comment: Is it possible that the German sentence is (at least without specific context) aiming at entertainment like bars and pubs, concerts, and the crowd enjoying the entertainment. The opposite of boring or deserted.  "Something going on" seems more ambiguous, at least standalone (it could be something sinister).